# Is the law of large numbers satisfied for the sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

Is the weak law of large numbers satisfied for the sequence of independent random variables 
$$
\xi_k,
$$ 
so that $$P(\xi_k=\sqrt k)=P(\xi_k=-\sqrt k)=1/2 \sqrt k, $$$$P(\xi_k=0)=1-1/\sqrt k ?$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Define $X_k= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{\xi_i}}{k}$.

Note that $E[X_k]=0$ holds for all $k$.

$Var(X_k)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ which tends to $0$ as k tends to $\infty$

The above condition are sufficient to say that $X_k \to 0$ in probability.

But this is exactly what WLLN says. So the answer to your question is YES.

Comment: Why does $Var(X_k)=\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}$?

Comment: @daylegacy sorry made a silly mistake, corrected now.